# Dynamic type property based on another property value

Tags: typescript

I am making a type to enforce that this `DynamicColor` type is used correctly.

```
enum ColorsEnum {
  red = "red",
  green = "green",
  blue = "blue",
  yellow = "yellow",
}

type ColorsMapperType = {
  type: ColorsEnum
  red: {
    redProperty: string
  }
  green: {
    greenProperty: string
  }
  blue: {
    blueProperty: string
  }
  yellow: {
    yellowProperty: string
  }
}

type ColorsMapper = Omit<ColorsMapperType, "type">

export type DynamicColor = {
  [ColorType in keyof ColorsMapper]: {
    [Prop in 'type' | ColorType]: Prop extends 'type' ? ColorType : ColorsMapper[ColorType]
  }
}[keyof ColorsMapper]
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sanderson-niqez?file=/src/index.ts

I have it mostly working, however I want the `type` field in the `DynamicColor` type to be the correct `ColorEnum` type.

***Right now, I get autocomplete for the **string** values of `ColorEnum`, but not the actual enum type.***

For example, the following code should be valid:

```
const color: DynamicColor = {
  type: ColorsEnum.green,
  green: {
    greenProperty: "1",
  },
}
```

None of the following code should be valid

```
const color0: DynamicColor = {
  type: "green", // invalid because not of ColorsEnum type
  green: {
    greenProperty: "1",
  },
}

const color1: DynamicColor = {
  type: ColorsEnum.blue, // invalid because property "blue" is not included
}

const color2: DynamicColor = {
  type: ColorsEnum.blue, // invalid because color property does not match correct type (ColorsEnum.blue should require a "blue" property)
  green: {
    greenProperty: "1",
  }
}

const color3: DynamicColor = {
  type: ColorsEnum.blue, // invalid because more than one color property is included
  blue: {
    blueProperty: "1",
  }
  green: {
    greenProperty: "1",
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance, and if there are other ways to improve this code I'm all ears.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that when the `type` in a `ColorMapper` object is `blue`, the only property it has is `blue`? I.e. you're discriminating the fields by the `type`? If so, you could just make separate types for the correct type-to-property combo and create an union type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

Comment: @cbr that's correct, however the `ColorsMapperType` type (I renamed it from `ColorMapper`) has constraints in our domain and needs to stay as the same model. I'm hoping to do this without changing that type at all.

Specifically, the type is being used as a GraphQL input type. GraphQL doesn't allow union input types, so we needed to resort to something like what I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to map all items in the `ColorsEnum` to another type like so (pseudocode)
`{ type: T; [T]: ColorsMapper[T] }`.
Fortunately, that is possible with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).
Here is a solution I found.

```js
enum ColorsEnum {
  red = "red",
  green = "green",
  blue = "blue",
  yellow = "yellow",
}

type ColorsMapper = {
  type: ColorsEnum
  red: {
    redProperty: string
  }
  green: {
    greenProperty: string
  }
  blue: {
    blueProperty: string
  }
  yellow: {
    yellowProperty: string
  }
}
type MapToColorType<T> = T extends ColorsEnum ? { [key in T]: ColorsMapper[T] } & { type: T } : never;
type Result = MapToColorType<ColorsEnum>;

const color: Result = {
  type: ColorsEnum.green,
  green: {
    greenProperty: "1",
  },
}
```

You can play around with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM4FFzQN4FgBQUUywAJlALxQBEJp1ANAUQOYmiU1vCiPNQAjBGGCdqQkX0JQAnsARIA7mLkK4iqQF8CBAC4yADqPhI0AWQCGBo8k55p%20owC5YiFBiz86L%200SJ0ABWQ4G30XVF1kAEsQFn5taW5QH35WdhAgkOBkMKgI6Nj4-glgFOkiEszQmXDImLjpBKJVJTK-WXklKuzc-Pqi-ATHUUsDABU4ExQxw2AAHjGAPk4xqGAAD11QUlRXUw9IKAB%20KGwoAG0Aa2AZKBioMYBdFynzKxtzp6hNKAAyU6gwxcqx%20LhAwAAbtkANx6WZQABKwFQYAQuk4owmrxmRjmrwOEEWsPwBAAxnAQBEoOTTC4kSi0XZ%20EC9u5MJAAHRJEBMRLpNp%20bndHI1GgARikRE0vM0QA).

**Explanation**

The thing is that conditional types are [distributive on union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). That means that the condition is applied to all members of the union. Enums are basically union of all the possible values. We can leverage that to map every member of the enum to a particular type.